# How to reduce the memory usage of an x86 assembler to compile a single large 200MB+ file?

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, yasm

I'm trying to assemble a >200MB x86 asm file with GAS in a VM with 4GB of RAM.  Unfortunately, GAS quickly consumes all system memory and gets killed.  I've also tried with the `--reduce-memory-overheads` flag, but the same result occurs.

I've also tried using yasm, but it also runs out of memory.

I know assemblers aren't really designed to handle files of this size, but I'm also surprised that they use so much memory trying to do so (why is this the case?).

The actual code is just one big function, split into several parts, so theoretically possible to break up into separate functions (or do they need to be separate files?), but is there any way to assemble this without splitting up the function?  I could also allocate more RAM, but I suspect that it wouldn't help much for the amount of RAM I have available (I would've thought 4GB to be plenty).

Comment: Did you hand write the function or is it generated by some compiler?

Comment: The code is generated by a script (you could consider it to be like a compiler I suppose).

Comment: Is it *your* script/compiler? Can you modify it to generate multiple functions instead of one?

Comment: Yes I can (as mentioned above), but I'm hoping to do it without having to split it up.  Thanks for the responses by the way.

Comment: Well then, increase the per-process memory limit on the VM and/or create a larger pagefile.

Comment: Ah, the more RAM solution.  Seems like there's no good way to do this then - a shame since I didn't think this would be a problem.  Thanks for your help Seva!

Comment: Write your own assembler :)